# What does a "context is rendered using a software renderer" error mean?

Tags: windows, opengl, sdl

I've been using SDL to set up an OpenGL rendering context embedded within a form, and everything's worked fine.  Now I'm trying to use a SDL-created window, but I'm getting some very strange errors.  Trying to create a texture fails with an inexplicable `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.

I ran it under gDEBugger to get a better look at what's going on, and the first error comes earlier than that.  When I'm creating the window, and SDL calls `wglMakeCurrent`, it gives a GL error:

```
Error Code: AP_USING_SOFTWARE_RENDERER_ERROR
Error Description: Context 2 is rendered using a software renderer (Vendor: , Renderer: )
```

Searching for either of those lines on Google gives me nothing in English (except the question I asked about this on the SDL mailing list, which got me nowhere) and the non-English results seem to be discussing completely different parts of OpenGL than I'm working with here.

So I guess this is a bit of a long shot, but does anyone have any idea what's going on and where this error comes from?  After this point, all sorts of things (such as texture setup, rectangular/NPOT texture mode and shaders) fail, making OpenGL unusable.

Answer (score 0):

This means that sdl cannot work with the video hardware and is working with software renderer. Try to update the drivers and see if there is a change.

Comment: And yet SDL works fine on the same hardware but with a slightly different program setup.  My drivers are up to date, and I don't see this problem anywhere else.  How do I figure out where the problem lies?

Comment: I think the problem is with your video drivers. When you use the SDL_SetVideoMode() do you use the SDL_HWSURFACE flag?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I'm using SDL 1.3, not SDL 1.2.

Comment: Will look into issue, but in the coming hours.

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes when Windows cannot find driver support for the desired graphic options then it resorts to a (slow) software renderer. I've seen it occur when asking for 32-bit depth buffer. Decreasing it to 16-bit fixed it.

Here is the setup code I use myself:

```
var
  Flags : SDL.UINT32;
  Mode : PSDL_Surface;
begin
  Flags := SDL_OPENGL or SDL_RESIZABLE;

  Width := 800;
  Height := 600;

  SDL_WM_SetCaption(Title, nil);

  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );

  Mode := SDL_SetVideoMode(Width, Height, 0, flags);
end
```